# Perform native account migration to Office 365 from Suite G ,trough API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, google-workspace, microsoft-graph-mail, google-email-migration

Microsoft Graph has a native way of performing migrations from G Suite email boxes through a native tool.

I wonder if there is a way to use this migration through the API

This method does not require individual account passwords, only account administrator permission settings

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/Exchange/mailbox-migration/perform-g-suite-migration

The documentation describes a series of steps that need to be executed through the accounts administrative panel, making use of the G Suite API for obtaining the data.

Answer (score 0):

Manage Migration Batch to microsoft mailbox is possible through [Microsoft Exchange PowerShell API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/move-and-migration/new-migrationbatch?view=exchange-ps)

Looking into Exchange PowerShell documentation i found a way to create a new migration like the migration possible on the [new migration tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/Exchange/mailbox-migration/perform-g-suite-migration)

Soon I will try to use this API and add here any update